# How do you load collections that live on a rails' action besides index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, batman.js

Batmanjs sample project [Classifieds](https://github.com/Shopify/batman-classifieds) used to do this by passing a :url option to override the default resource name, but this has now been deprecated.

```
Classifieds.Ad.load {url: "/ads/search.json?q=#{params.q}"}, (error, records) =>
        throw error if error
        @set 'searchAds', records
```

I have seen most people pass query params to the index action and handle logic depending on the filters passed. Is there a working example somewhere of how to load a collection from a rails action other than index?